# How to use the_permalink as redirect url in Facebook app?

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress

I am creating Facebook app but the problem is i want to use word-press's the_permalink as redirect url but its not working its showing redirect url=the_permalink(), here is my code

```
define('REDIRECT_URI',"the_permalink()");
```

I am new to php so i think i am lacking some basic thing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Wordpress. But I think you have to remove the quotes from *the_permalink()*.

Answer (score 0):

At first remove quotes:

```
define('REDIRECT_URI',the_permalink());
```

`the_permalink()` - function that return current page url - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink